# amazon aurora read_only {TrueIfReplica}

Tags: amazon-aurora

I have {TrueIfReplica} for read_only in parameter group for Aurora. I setup my aurora to replicate from an external master that is vanilla MySQL. When I look at read_only in show variables it is 0; even though it is a replica. Why is this?

Comment: I suppose that this parameter will be set to true only when using Aurora replication. MySQL replication isn't the same solution as Aurora replication.

Comment: So you think it is true if you use replication natively in aws and not manually from external master?

Comment: I am sorry, my mistake. I meant innodb_read_only parameter, not read_only. read_only parameter can not be configured in Aurora and it is also set to OFF on replica, so it seems that read_only parameter is disabled on Aurora.

Comment: I am taking about the MySQL replica I setup to replicate from aurora